# How can I can access a property referred to another entity Sonata?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata

```
class Comment
{
    private $foreignId;
    private $foreignType;
```

And in my CommentAdmin

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper ->add('name', 'string', array('template' => 'AdminBundle:Comment:name.html.twig', 'label' => 'Name'))
```

so how can I access the name property of the entity whose id = foreignId without relations tables. I would like to do something like that:

```
{{ object.foreignEntityId.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible!

If you only have the ID and NOT the object itself or i missunderstand your problem

Oskar

Comment: Yes, I have only the id and type. Also have a method in my service getForeignEntityData($type, $id) which returns $data filler properly. Is it mandatory to have relations tables? Thanks.

Comment: The problem here, ist that the ListMapper is used to build the outline of the list. You only have the object in the template, so you could write a twig extension where you inject the type and the ID and doing the database stuff inside the extension

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503370/sonata-admin-configurelistfields-show-through-query)? Where create the extension?